What is the point of honeypot?
Please take a look at this example specifically: https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/honeypot/
Based on my understanding, an ordinary withdraw transaction will also revert. In fact, every withdraw transaction will revert, making this contract just useless.
What is the point of someone using honeypot then? Even if someone is willing to deposit a few ETH to "attract" hackers, how would honeypot distinguish hackers from benign user if every withdraw function reverts?
addendum: My question boils down to this: what's the point of honeypot if it rejects all withdrawals when it's impossible to determine if the user had a malicious intent or not.

The point in the example is that the logger is passed as constructor parameter
constructor(Logger _logger) {
    logger = Logger(_logger);
}

An unsuspecting user may believe that it only emits events:
function log(address _caller, uint256 _amount, string memory _action)
    public
{
    emit Log(_caller, _amount, _action);
}

The reality is that calling an external logger could do much more. The contract Logger is only used as an interface, its code is there to fool unsuspecting users.
In the example it just reverts withdrawals. A more realistic behavior could be to add a backdoor for the honeypot's owner to withdraw the whole balance.

In the example that I've linked, the author suggests that the honeypot was meant to "catch" malicious hackers utilizing the method that you've mentioned. What you have described, however, sounds more like what a malicious hacker would do.

@hyunchel That description is incorrect. The target are developers that started learning solidity but don't know the odd cases of the language. On the surface contract appear to have some "honey" that is easy to access, but if you try to extract it there is a trap inside. The traps are the way solidity and blockchain work that isn't the same as other languages on a PC. In this case Logger is there but it is never used, other honeypots use internal functions, etc.
